# Sql query on 3 tables (count)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have three tables: S (Staff), C (Clients), O (Operations). Below are the screenshots of the tables.
[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I print for every city the number of clients and the number of staff who live there?
So, the table would have 3 columns: City, Count(Clinets), Count(Stuff)

Comment: What's the schema of operations? You pasted clients twice.

Comment: Sorry, now it's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select city, sum(clients) as clients, sum(staff) as staff
from 
(
  select city, count() as clients, null as staff from clients group by city
  union all 
  select city, null, count() from staff group by city
) tmp
group by city
```